# Compute duration of audio file at a given URL endpoint (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio

For context, I'm building a podcasting app that fetches podcasts from various RSS feeds to be played in the app; I want to store in DB and show each audio's duration to my users. However, duration is not a required field in RSS feeds, so I must compute this property separately, given the audio file endpoint, if the property doesn't exist.

How would I go about doing this?